# how to change background color of div when radio button inside the div got checked in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

My code looks like this

```
<div class="radioButtonImage">
<div class="radio-wrapper">
    <input class type="radio" id="Infant" value>
<img src="datarimage/png;" height="25" width="25" alt> 
<label for="Infant" class="input-label">Infant</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-wrapper">
    <input class type="radio" id="Child" value>
<img src="datarimage/png;" height="25" width="25" alt> 
<label for="Child" class="input-label">child</label>
</div>
</div>
```

my requirement is when radio button is checked whole div with class radio-wrapper backgroundcolor should be changed to blue and border should be set to 1px solid black. how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a `useEffect` to update `backgroundColor` whenever the `radioButton` state changes.

```js
const [backgroundColor, setBackGroundColor] = React.useState("black");
const [radioButton, setRadioButton] = React.useState(false);
            
const setBackGroundColorFunc = () => setRadioButton(radioButton => !radioButton)

useEffect(() => {
  setBackGroundColor(radioButton ? "blue" : "white");
}, [radioButton]);
              

<div class="radio-wrapper" style={{backgroundColor: backgroundColor}}>
  <input type="radio" id="Infant" checked={radioButton} onChange={setBackGroundColorFunc} />
  <img src="datarimage/png;" height="25" width="25" alt>
  <label for="Infant" class="input-label" style={{backgroundColor:backgroundColor}}>Infant</label>
</div>
```

Comment: what if checked inside input  tag is being used for something else? how to set checked then? and i want to set border as well.

Comment: you can declare a new state for others need to be effected from radiobutton. For border, you can define one more state to declare border's values or write as ; style={{border: radioButton ? "0px" : "3px solid blue"}}

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `:has()` function and the `:checked` selector in css, like this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked

```css
.radio-wrapper:has(input:checked){
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioButtonImage">
  <div class="radio-wrapper">
    <input class type="radio" id="Infant" value>
    <img src="datarimage/png;" height="25" width="25" alt>
    <label for="Infant" class="input-label">Infant</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-wrapper">
    <input class type="radio" id="Child" value>
    <img src="datarimage/png;" height="25" width="25" alt>
    <label for="Child" class="input-label">child</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is, actually you can check it by running the code snippet